# Printing array from XML - C#

Tags: c#, xml, printing, methods

Im in the process of working with XML data and what Im trying to do is;

- User selects name value from a dropdownlist
- for each node with above name, value is added to a list
- list then converted to string array
- **printing the array to test, no output is given
- string array converted to int array (to allow computation on
  array)
- **Print provides no output again

Here is the code I've produced, I get no errors just no output so I cant tell if the arrays have been populated.

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text=="Cabin")
{
    //Load XML document
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
    // xnList = nodes -> rows with Cabin
    XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/root/row[@name='Cabin']");

    //create a string list
    List<string> strvalues = new List<string>();
    //populate list with values @ node Cabin
    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
    {
        strvalues.Add(xn["value"].InnerText);
    }

    //convert list to array
    strvalues.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        //print array
        Console.WriteLine(strvalues[i]);
    }
    //convert string array to int array for data manipulation
    int[] values = strvalues.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        //print array
        Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is a section of the XML file also;

```
 <root>
  <row>
    <var name="Name" value="Garcia" />
    <var name=" Surname" value=" Jose" />
    <var name=" Country" value=" Cuba" />
    <var name=" Job" value="Software Developer" />
    <var name=" Cabin" value="345" />
  </row>
  <row>
    <var name="Name" value="Lenon" />
    <var name=" Surname" value="Tim" />
    <var name=" Country" value="USA" />
    <var name=" Job" value="SoftwareDeveloper" />
    <var name=" Cabin" value="444" />
  </row>
 </root>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath expression is wrong, as the `<row>` element has no attribute named `name` (and it's also missing the space in the actual name attribute value).

Did you mean `/root/row/var[@name=' Cabin']` or possibly `/root/row[var/@name=' Cabin']` (if you wanted the `<row>` element; though looking at your code that's not the case).

---

Additionally, the line `strvalues.ToArray()` does nothing, because you don't assign the result to anything. `ToArray` doesn't modify the list, it returns a new array with the same contents as the list. There is no real reason to convert the list to an array in this code either.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the spacing issue the reason for this is I converted a .csv file to XML so there was obviously a spacing issue I overlooked. As far as converting to an array I need to be able to pass in an array of data, so I just thought it best to convert the list to a int array ultimately

Comment: The code to convert it to an `int` array is fine, it's the earlier call to `strvalues.ToArray()` that is superfluous (and has no effect because like I said, you're ignoring the return value).

Answer (score 1):

The attribute value for name in the sample XML is " Cabin" - note the leading space.

The attribute value tested against name in the XPath query is "Cabin" - no leading space.

So you never find any nodes.

The generic answer to looking at this would be to set a breakpoint immediately after you create the node list and to check the content at that point.

As a further aside, Linq to XML is much more pleasant to work with if that's available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a console window associated with your solution? I think you're using a UI and there is no console window (so Console.WriteLine won't output anything). You can attach one, but for debug I can suggest Debug.WriteLine:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/debug-write

Also, you should check if your arrays being populated in debug mode.